# How to adjust border offset on inline text link?

Tags: css

I'm using `border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;` for my anchor tags instead of `text-decoration: underline;` so I could have a dotted line.

Would anyone know how to adjust the offset of the border to be closer or farther away from the text?

[Example on Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw6bH/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `display` to `inline-block`, you can use `line-height` to move the border closer or further away.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw6bH/2/).

Comment: Excellent. `display: inline-block;` and `line-height` was exactly what I was looking for thanks.